# DELETE ROW where ID = $id not deleting the row requested

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to implement a feature which allows me to delete students from a students list. (which is a table)

Though when I click delete it does not delete the student in that current row HOWEVER.. if i change my query to DELETE FROM students WHERE id = 1 for example.. it works. So, I'm believing the problem lies with not being able to grab the id from the current row however, I'm not sure where I am going wrong with this.

//StudentsList.php

```
<?php include ('../resources/styling.html'); ?>
<?php include ('adminNavbar.php'); ?>

<!--HTML styling of the table that outputs the database entries, bootstrap styling-->

<div class="container content-area">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="panel">
<br>

<div class="text-center border border-light p-5">
<p class="h4 mb-4">All Student Accounts</p>
</div>
<br>

<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Surname</th>
      <th scope="col">Programme</th>
      <th scope="col">Student ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Delete</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

<?php
include ('../resources/config.php');

$sql = "SELECT id,firstname, surname, programme, studentid FROM students";
$result = $db->query($sql);

// while loop to output data of each row for each student in database

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo '<tr>
    <td scope="row">' . $row["id"]. '</td>
                  <td>' . $row["firstname"] .'</td>
                  <td> '.$row["surname"] .'</td>
                  <td> '.$row["programme"] .'</td>
                  <td> '.$row["studentid"] .'</td>
                  <td ><a class="btn btn-danger"   href="MLdelete.php?id=".$row["id"].""</a> Delete</td>
    </tr>';

}
$db->close();
?>

</tbody>
</table>

<div class="text-center border border-light p-5">
<a href="createStudent.php" class="btn btn-primary">Add New Student Account</a>
</div>
```

//MLdelete.php

```
<?php
require ( '../resources/config.php' );

if(isset($_GET["id"])){

    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET["id"]);
    // sql to delete a record
    $query = "DELETE FROM students WHERE id ='{$id}'";

    $del=mysqli_query($db,$query);

    if ($del) {
       header("Location: StudentsList.php");
    } else {
        echo "Error deleting record: " . $db->error;
    }
}
    $db->close();

?>
```

Basically, when I click the DELETE button for a row, nothing happens.

Comment: firstly use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection attacks. Also what does `echo $_GET['id'];` return?

Comment: This is confusing because you said that if you DELETE FROM students it works fine, your code shows DELETE FROM students which then works. What code do you use that does not work?

Comment: Sorry ill edit.. when I click the DELETE button nothing happens

Comment: Also, never use GET for deletion. That's a sensitive operation that should be using a form with POST. If the page is public, a bot might trigger the deletion of all your records.

Answer (score 2):

You did not properly quote your `<a>` link.

It should be

```
<td ><a class="btn btn-danger"   href="MLdelete.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '"</a> Delete</td>
```

Also use prepared statements as per my comment. This will prevent SQL injection attacks.

Check out prepared statements explanation and examples via the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Thanks.. still, nothing happens when I click that delete button.

Comment: fixed. try now.

Comment: Completely saved me I've been pulling my hair out to find the problem. I've upvoted your answer! thanks so much

Comment: pleasure :) and don't forget to check out the prepared statements link i included. Its very important